# VBA: Custom data type and function (return value)

Tags: vba, function, custom-data-type

I get a compile error at the last line when testing the following: (Only public user defined types that are defined in a public object module can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions.)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Type aType
    P_Col As Integer
    P_Rad As Single
    P_X As Single
    P_Y As Single
End Type


Function MakePatterns() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim circles() As aType

For i = 1 To 5
    ReDim Preserve circles(i)
    circles(i).P_Col = Int(i / 2)
    circles(i).P_Rad = i
    circles(i).P_X = i * 10 + 1
    circles(i).P_Y = i * 10 + 5

Next

For i = 1 To 5
    Debug.Print circles(i).P_Col; circles(i).P_Rad; _
     circles(i).P_X; circles(i).P_Y
Next
MakePatterns = circles

End Function
```

---

Is there a way to use TYPE and Function together to return an array? Or is there a more effective way?

Comment: Sorry I think I made a mistake in the function (as aType rather than as Variant) but that only changed the error to a Type Mismatch.

Comment: Since you are passing the Type in OR out of a function, class objects should be good to use. Moreover use Collection instead of array.

Comment: @user110084  try the code in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below **Sub** **"TestCallFunction"** calls the **Function** **"MakePatterns"**, and after it prints the first array received back from the function in the Immediate window.

```
Option Explicit

Public Type aType
    P_Col As Integer
    P_Rad As Single
    P_X As Single
    P_Y As Single
End Type


Sub TestCallFunction()

Dim x()                 As aType
Dim i                   As Integer

x = MakePatterns

' print the first result received from Function MakePatterns
Debug.Print x(1).P_Col & ";" & x(1).P_Rad & ";" & x(1).P_X & ";" & x(1).P_Y

End Sub

Public Function MakePatterns() As aType()

Dim i                   As Integer
Dim circles()           As aType

For i = 1 To 5
    ReDim Preserve circles(i)
    circles(i).P_Col = Int(i / 2)
    circles(i).P_Rad = i
    circles(i).P_X = i * 10 + 1
    circles(i).P_Y = i * 10 + 5
Next

For i = 1 To 5
    Debug.Print circles(i).P_Col; circles(i).P_Rad; _
    circles(i).P_X; circles(i).P_Y
Next

MakePatterns = circles

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much Shai. So, were my mistakes in the MakePatterns function: 
(1) not declaring it Public and 
(2) declaring it as "aType" instead of an array "aType()" ?

Comment: @user110084 are you asking where are your mistakes ? please mark as answer

Comment: @user110084 you need to declare the Function with the type you want it to return, so I modified to `Public Function MakePatterns() As aType()`

Comment: Thanks Mukul. I did read up on Collections but I have not tried it yet. Class feels daunting at this point. It has been decades since I last did Fortran and my MS Office VBA has been really poor, always done out of necessity (ugly and inefficient for sure). So, a ton of relearning.

Comment: Extrapolating from this, how do I have an array of
Patterns ( Circles(), Squares(), Triangle() )

I tried defining
    Public Type bType
         Shp1 as variant
         Shp2 as variant
         Shp3 as variant
    End Type

and then Patterns(i).Shp1 = Circles etc

but that did not work

Comment: @user110084 I suggest you open a new post, with your new updated code, and ask advice from the forum from all users (and me as well)

Comment: Will do that. Apologies.